# Data Binding ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, data-binding, combobox

I have a class `Product` with some `properties` that are set by a `WCF` `async` call to the database. I have two `textboxes` and a `combobox` and I want to bind the `Product` object to these `controls`. Binding `textboxes` was easy and It works, my only problem is, I dont know how to bind the SelectedItem to the property `ProductTypeName`?

`Product` class

```
public class Product
{
 public string Code{get;set;}
 public string Description{get;set;}
 public string ProductTypeName { get; set;}
}
```

XAML for `textbox`

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         x:Name="txtDetails" 
         Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

In code behind I simply create an object of `Product` and bind it to the DataContext. Works fine for `textboxes` but have no clue how to do it for `ComboBox`

```
Product p = new Product();
product.Description = e.Result[0].Description;
product.Code = e.Result[0].Code;
product.ProductTypeName = e.Result[0].ProductTypeName
this.DataContext = p
```

Now,I want the SelectedItem of my `combobox` to be set according to `p.ProductTypeName` but I dont know how to do that.

**NOTE:** My `ComboBox` is already populated and set at `0th index`. How can I bind it according to `p.ProductTypeName`? I think I just need to make changes in my XAML.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboProductType" 
          DisplayMemberPath="ProductTypeName" 
          SelectedValuePath="ProductTypeID" 
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your XAML code: SelectedItem = "{Binding ProductTypeName}"

Comment: I did. But the `SelectedIndex` remains `0`. I had `"Fashion"` in `ProductTypeName` which is at `Index` `7`. It's `SelectedIndex` should be `7` now but no change

Comment: Ah. OK. You preloaded ComboBox with integers 0,1,... and you want to select appropriate item? If so, you should have integer ProductTypeId property in your Product and you should bind SelectedIndex to ProductTypeId.

Comment: No I haven't preloaded with integers. Its preloaded with `ProductTypeID` and `ProductTypeName` fetched from `DB`. Then later I m fetching a particular `ProductTypeName` and I want the `SelectedIndex` to move to that item instead of staying at default `0th Index`

Comment: In that case you shouldn't bind ProductTypeID to ComboBox SelectedValue, bind ProductTypeName instead: SelectedValuePath="ProductTypeName" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductTypeName}"